# How does activateJavaScript.org detect your browser without JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If you'll visit this [website](http://activatejavascript.org/) with your JavaScript disabled, it will automatically jump to the instructions specific to your web browser. How can they do that? How do they detect the browser you're using without JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They check your [`User-Agent` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Agent).

Comment: Then how do they choose with content to display?

Comment: On the actual homepage they're showing you instructions for `your` browser. I'm sure that's not the static content in their HTML?

Comment: @user1090389: Yes.  They do that using server-side code.  I fail to see your question.

Comment: The server is delivering the Homepage html based on your user-agent header?

Comment: @user1090389: The server is handle your request in any case. All they in addition is examine this particular header field to determine the content.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin They have to serve each web browser specifically, I'm sure it's not as fast as getting a request and delivering the content. Each request requires different content to be delivered

Comment: @user1090389: That is the case for every website. Stackoverflow handles thousands of different requests from different users/browsers. Examining the user-agent header is actually simpler (form this perspective). There is only a handful of browsers compared to an ever growing number of questions.

Comment: @user1090389: On the contrary; that's not very different.  It's just an `if` or a database lookup (as opposed to a disk read).

Answer (score 0):

They probably use the **HTTP headers**: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html